# Maven Shade Plugin Create Jar Without Dependencies and load dependency jars from another location

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I want to create a jar file using maven-shade-plugin without 3rd party dependencies. However, 3rd party dependency jars should be copied to some folder (say libs).
So, when I distribute my application, I distribute main.jar and libs folder together, so when I launch the created main jar, it should load dependencies from libs folder.

Is it possible to do this in maven-shade-plugin? then how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved as maven shade plugin extracts all dependency jar file content(class files) in to main jar file. However, this can be achieved using `maven-jar-plugin` and `maven-dependency-plugin`. This is my build settings:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I have also built a big jar directly through maven shade plugin.

Here is my usage to build a spring application in one jar including all spring framework dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>${project.build.mainClass}</Main-Class>
                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                            <Specification-Title>${project.artifactId}</Specification-Title>
                            <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                            <Implementation-Title>${project.artifactId}</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                            <Implementation-Vendor-Id>${project.groupId}</Implementation-Vendor-Id>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In addition about the comparison with [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), as mentioned in the HP, Maven Assembly Plugin only provide some basic support, however Maven Shade Plugin could provide more control.